Java's String.split(delim) leaves an empty string in the start if the original string starts with the delimiter
If you use .split(delim) on a string that starts with the delimiter, your resulting array will start with an empty string. Here is the example:
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = " aaa bbb ccc ".split("[^\\w]+");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
}


the result is:
[, aaa, bbb, ccc]

Although I expected it to be
[aaa, bbb, ccc]


Always read the Javadoc: "When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however never produces such empty leading substring."  The answer by @DCurtis is one possible solution.

So this is just how the method works and there's no way to make it work as I wanted...

Yes, it’s a feature, not a bug. By definition, a delimiter comes between elements. If your input begins with the delimiter that means the first element is missing. An empty String object is the appropriate way in Java to represent missing text, either that or a null.

You can use (?i)[a-z0-9_]+:

(?i) is an insensitive flag, which ignores and relaxes case sensitivity (e.g., apple, Apple and APPLE are treated the same).
[a-z0-9_]: are the list of chars allowed and you can change it, if you want. (Note: A-Za-z0-9_ and \w are the same. )

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(?i)[a-z0-9_]+";
        final String string = " aaa bbb ccc  \n"
                + "aaa bbb        \n"
                + "       ccc        12aaa _bbb 1_ccc          hhh               ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

Prints
Full match: aaa
Full match: bbb
Full match: ccc
Full match: aaa
Full match: bbb
Full match: ccc
Full match: 12aaa
Full match: _bbb
Full match: 1_ccc
Full match: hhh


You can also save the matches in an ArrayList():
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(?i)[a-z0-9_]+";
        final String string = " aaa bbb ccc  \n"
                + "aaa bbb        \n"
                + "       ccc        12aaa _bbb 1_ccc          hhh               ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            matches.add(matcher.group(0));
        }

        for (String match : matches) {
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }
}


Prints
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
bbb
ccc
12aaa
_bbb
1_ccc
hhh


You can also use split():
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string = " aaa bbb ccc  \n"
                + "aaa bbb        \n"
                + "       ccc        12aaa _bbb 1_ccc          hhh               ";
        final String regex = "\\s+";

        String[] parts = string.split(regex);
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String part : parts) {
            if (!part.isEmpty()) {
                matches.add(part);
            }
        }

        for (String match : matches) {
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }
}



So in fact the correct answer would be to use Matcher and Pattern to split the line instead of .split() method...

@AndreyVoeyko That's one way to do it. Time complexity is O(N). You can also use String[] parts = string.split(regex);.

In case your interested, here is a stream solution.  This particular one matches on anything that has no white space.

[\\S]+ - character class of one or more non-white space characters.

String str = "     aaa  Foo  bbb    ccc  ab123d _aksks_ ";

String[] result = Pattern.compile("[\\S]+").matcher(str).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

prints
[aaa, Foo, bbb, ccc, ab123d, _aksks_]

You can control the delimiter by modifying the character class in the regex. So if the string delimited using a combination of white space and commas, you could use [^\\s,]+. Which says match on anything except white space and commas.

Use String.trim() method before split()

Unfortunately, this is applicable only in the example I've provided. In fact, I need something like ". aaa bbb ccc" to become [aaa,bbb,ccc] as well.

In fact, I need something like ". aaa bbb ccc" to become [aaa,bbb,ccc] as well That simply sounds like malformed input/bad parsing. Why wouldn't it be [., aaa, bbb, ccc]? If that really is the case, it sounds like you don't want String::split at all
